# Twitter API Twitter4j getUserID

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I am using Twitter4j to get tweets from the user's I'm following. Getting 1000 per time, but I'm a bit stuck on how I would include user ID and username in the out put.

Here is the code I'm using in order to get the tweets:

```
try {
            ResponseList<Status> a = twitter.getHomeTimeline(new Paging(1,1000));

            for (Status b: a){
                System.out.println(b.getText());
            }
        }
```

Does anybody know what I'd have to add in order to output the ID, Username and then the Tweet?

Thanks
Z19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the id and user name using following methods.

`User user = b.getUser()` --> Return the user associated with the status.
then using `user.getId()` and `user.getName()` you can get the id and user name.

```
try {
            ResponseList<Status> a = twitter.getHomeTimeline(new Paging(1,1000));

            for (Status b: a){
                long userId = b.getUser().getId();// user Id
                String userName = b.getUser().getName(); // user name
                String tweetText = b.getText(); // tweet

                System.out.println(userId+" "+userName+" "+tweetText);
            }
        }
```

For more info you can refer following links:

1. [Twitter 4j Status](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Status.html)
2. [Twitter 4j User](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/User.html)

Comment: you've helped me out here, worked great. Thank you for that, I appreciate it.

Comment: although the first String  userID needed to be "long"; works great thanks.